# What are these three options on the kart selection screen?

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

There are a few new features in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, some of which are enablable on the kart selection screen:

[image: Options accessible with L/SL, Y/<, and R/SR on the kart selection screen]

I figure the one in the middle is motion controls, but I have no idea what the other two are.  We tried playing with them off and on and didn't really notice a difference.  Even the "info" screen on the title page didn't give any info on it.  What the heck do they do?

Comment: I gotta say, for a game that doesn't come with a booklet; they really should have been more clear about this.  Me and my friend had to google-fu it before we started playing to make sure we didn't have terrible options selected.

Comment: @JMac they are pretty poor illustrations for what they mean.  They aren't very heuristic.

Comment: @TimmyJim Exactly.  Tilt-control was fairly obvious at least, and that is likely the most disruptive.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looking at this screenshot for reference:

[image: Controls]

<sub><sub>[Source](https://www.polygon.com/2017/4/28/15475694/mario-kart-8-deluxe-turn-off-smart-steering)</sub></sub>

From left to right they are:

- Smart Steering
- Tilt Controls
- Auto-acceleration

They toggle these options either on or off.

What is smart steering and auto-acceleration? As [one source](https://www.destructoid.com/a-young-disabled-girl-can-finally-play-mario-kart-thanks-to-the-smart-steering-feature-433798.phtml) words it:

> The two options are pretty self explanatory, but they allow you to either have the game auto steer or leave the gas pedal down. It lowers the skill ceiling for new players by letting them focus more on learning the courses or using items without having to fiddle with anything else. It can definitely automate the experience a bit, but it hardly ruins it for "expert" players.

It looks like for expert players, you may want to disable these.  But for people with disabilities such as the source discusses, or if you are a new player, they make the game much more playable.

Comment: Ah yes.  We never paused so we didn't see this screen.  It would be helpful to know what "Smart Steering" and "Auto-acceleration" means though

Comment: @ChaseSandmann "Smart Steering" helps a player going around corners or getting to close to the edge stay on track, it essentially prevents player from falling off of the map.  "Auto-Acceleration" makes it so you don't have to hold down the "Y" button (or whatever your acceleration button is), the game "holds down the gas" for you.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann edited in some more info.

Comment: Good info, thanks.  After more research, it looks like they also added a third level of drifting boost called "ultra mini-turbo" that [can only be accessed when Smart Steering is off](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_8_Deluxe#Differences_from_the_original), so that's a good reason to turn it off for higher-skilled players.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann Hmm, neat that it doesn't apply with smart-steering enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:
(From left to right)

1. Smart Steering, Pretty much you can't fall off the edge or run into *some* obstacles. You can although *jump* off the edge, like with a ramp.
2. Tilt Controls, steer your kart with tilt controls
3. Auto-Acceleration, you can move your kart without pressing any buttons. You can slow it down or stop it by braking.