Are there hidden player assist tools in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe?
While playing with my young children, I've noticed that I find it difficult to fall to the back of the pack in a split-screen MK race, while they consistently are lapped by every other racer. I have gone an entire starting lap without giving my controller inputs, and they remain behind me because the computer keeps me moving and on the track. It's difficult for me to even fall off without the assist yanking me back on, but my child has a hard time staying in the middle of the track. If they let go of the gas, they remain still (unlike when I let off the gas). Is there some character or player (1p/2p) setting that is helping me but not them?
If it matters, I typically play Yoshi with standard stuff as 2p.
They typically play Peach with the ATV as 1p.
We each use a horizontal joycon.

They aren't hidden... not intentionally.  Look here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/308159/what-are-these-three-options-on-the-kart-selection-screen/308160#308160 If that answers your question, we can mark this as a duplicate.  It sounds like you have assists on, while your children don't!

Thank you! Yes. Such an opaque UX for such an otherwise universally approachable title.
